# Building subplots

Tags: python, dataframe, matplotlib

I'm trying to create a series of subplots:

```
count=0
fig1, axes1 = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=1, figsize=(10,80))
for x in b:
   """code gets data here as a dataframe"""
   axes1[count]=q1.plot()
   count=count+1
```

However this creates two plots rather than 2 subplots in one figure. I am using python 3.5 in Pycharm. Been racking my brain at what i'm doing wrong here

Comment: Is `q1` a pandas DataFrame?

Comment: ok I think I figured it out. Apologies on it

Comment: @DavidG. Yes. q1 is a dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating an array of axes (subplots) using `fig1, axes1 = plt.subplots(...)`. You are then overwriting elements of this array when you do

```
axes1[count]=q1.plot()
```

You are assigned the return value of `q1.plot()` to an element of that array.

What you probably want to do is to either use your axes to plot directly using `axes1[count].plot(...)` if you are using pure matplotlib. As you are using pandas, pass in your axes as an argument to the plotting function:

```
count=0
fig1, axes1 = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=1, figsize=(10,80))
for x in b:
   """code gets data here as a dataframe"""
   q1.plot(ax=axes1[count])
   count=count+1
```

Comment: Thank you. One further issue I have with this
When going through the loop part I will get the following error message when attempting to plot one of the dataframe in a subplot:

    ValueError: Shape of passed values is (2, 27), indices imply (2, 25) If break when attempting to plot for one of the dataframes

Comment: I don't know why that is happening. You need to create a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

I used the following

```
q1.plot(title=str(x), legend=True, ax=axes1[count])
```